# Problemas (VRaptor + Hibernate request)

Tags: hibernate, vraptor, java

Estou utilizando o `Vraptor` para desenvolver uma aplicação web. Mais em determinados testes, vi que o `Hibernate` está adicionando na base de dados, mas quando eu envio o `Result` para a minha pagina com uma nova lista daquele objeto que deletei do meu cliente, aparentemente ele está trazendo algo do cache. Na base meu cliente está com 3 itens e o `Hibernate` traz só os antigos 2.

Coloquei o Dao como `@RequestScoped`, justamente para não ter problemas deste tipo. Como Resolvo esse problema?

Código do dao:

```
public class DaoMaster {
private EntityManager manager;

@Inject
public DaoMaster(EntityManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

public DaoMaster() {
}

public void cria(Object o){
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.persist(o);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public void atualiza(Object o){
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.merge(o);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();

}

public void remove(Long id, Class<?> classe){
    Object o = buscaPorId(id, classe);
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.remove(o);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public Object buscaPorId(Long id,Class<?> classe){
    try{
        return manager.find(classe, id);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

public List<?> listaTodos(Class<?> classe){
    try{
        return manager.createQuery("select t from "+ classe.getSimpleName() +" t",classe).getResultList();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERRO: "+e);
        return null;
    }
}

public List<?> listaPorQueryModificada(String queryModificada, HashMap<String, Object> parametros, Class<?> classe){
    try{
        TypedQuery<?> query = manager.createQuery(queryModificada,classe);
        if(parametros != null && parametros.size() > 0){
            for(String key: parametros.keySet()){
                Object value = parametros.get(key);
                query.setParameter(key, value);
            }
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERRO: "+e);
        return null;
    }
}

public List<?> listaPorNamedQuery(String namedQuery, HashMap<String, Object> parametros,Class<?> classe){
    try{
        TypedQuery<?> query = manager.createNamedQuery(namedQuery,classe);
        if(parametros != null && parametros.size() > 0){
            for(String key: parametros.keySet()){
                Object value = parametros.get(key);
                query.setParameter(key, value);
            }
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERRO: "+e);
        return null;
    }
}

public Object buscaPorNamedQuery(String namedQuery,HashMap<String, Object> parametros,Class<?> classe){
    Object objeto;
    try{
        TypedQuery<?> query = manager.createNamedQuery(namedQuery,classe);
        if(parametros != null && parametros.size() > 0){
            for(String key: parametros.keySet()){
                Object value = parametros.get(key);
                query.setParameter(key, value);
            }
        }
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERRO: "+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

--Detalhamento--

Tenho uma tela que faço cadastro de subCategorias, ao cadastrar um novo item, chamo uma função com o Vraptor para adicionar, e no final mando ele redirecionar para a minha outra funcão que faz a chamada da tela. Na função da chamada da tela, listo todas as subCategorias com o hibernate e mando para o result, para poder mostrar na tela do usuário.

Só que tem vez que quando faço um cadastro de um novo item, a aplicação cadastra esse item na base, e quando vai para a funcão de chamar a tela novamente para fazer a nova pesquisa de todas as subCategorias existentes, parece que o hibernate está trazendo a antiga pesquisa da chamada anterior, onde não existia ainda aquele novo item que acabei de cadastrar, fazendo que o novo item não exista na tela.

Código das chamadas para o Vraptor:

```
@Admin
public void listaSubCategoria(Long categoriaID){

    List<SubCategoria> subCategorias = subCategoriaDao.listaPorCategoria(categoriaID);
    result.include("categoria",categoriaDao.buscaPorId(categoriaID));
    result.include("subCategorias", subCategorias);
    result.include("pagina", "categoria");
}

@Admin
public void adicionaSubCategoria(SubCategoria subCategoria, UploadedFile imagem){
    /*VERIFICAR SE JÁ EXISTE UMA SUB CATEGORIA COM O MESMO NOME PARA NÃO DAR ERRO*/
    //subCategoriaDao.adiciona(subCategoria,imagem);
    if(subCategoria.getId() != null){
        daoMaster.atualiza(subCategoria);
    }else{
        subCategoria.setCategoria((Categoria) daoMaster.buscaPorId(subCategoria.getCategoria().getId(), Categoria.class));
        daoMaster.cria(subCategoria);
    }

    adicionaImagem(NomenclaturaArquivo._NOMENCLATURA_IMAGEM_CATEGORIA, imagem, subCategoria.getId());

    result.redirectTo(this).listaSubCategoria(subCategoria.getCategoria().getId());
}
```

Comment: Você está comitando todas as operações de banco?

Comment: Você disse que está deletando, e que na base tem 3 clientes, porque então são 2 registros antigos? Não era pra ser 4?

Comment: Para não ter problemas com interceptadores, todos os processos do dao, passa pelo `manager.getTransaction().begin();` e `manager.getTransaction().commit();`, as informações mesmo não vindo para a tela atualizadas, estão cadastradas no banco, sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Coloca seu código na postagem e tente exemplificar um pouco melhor o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Tente comitar as consultas também. Coloque um sysout pra exibir a lista e veja se ela traz os dados certos.

Comment: Fiz o teste, e novamente o hibernate cadastrou correto na base, mais quando mostra na tela, não trouxe a nova informação. Fiz o print de todos antes de adicionar a lista na tela, e também não consta na lista da função. Se eu reiniciar o tomcat da aplicação o mesmo vai aparecer.

Comment: Esqueci e mencionar, não sei se pode ser alguma configuração que falta, mais estou utilizando o plugin da JPA no vraptor. Não gero meus Entity Manager com classes minhas.

Comment: não sei se pode ser isso pois nunca utilizei esse plugin, eu já tive um problema semelhante e resolvi comitando minhas consultas.

Comment: Você diz, chamando o begin da transação no início e o commit no fim, também nas funções de consulta?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Kelvin

Comment: @Techies fiz os testes, e aparentemente o problema realmente se resolve. Não sei realmente se vai resolver completamente com este pequeno teste que fiz, mais para esta simulação de erro que eu estava fazendo, resolveu. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda! Agradeço por ter dado atenção para meu problema.  Obrigado.

Comment: Por nada, se o problema foi resolvido eu irei colocar uma resposta pra poder ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema

Comment: @Techies Fiz os testes gerais nas outras telas do sistema, e nenhuma apresentou mais o problema. Posso dizer que sim, foi resolvido. Minhas consultas não estavam abrindo as novas transações e fechando no final.

Comment: Tranquilo, coloquei uma resposta, se ela te atende é só marcar como solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando seu código vi que você não está dando `commit` nas suas consultas. O `commit` basicamente encerra a transação salvando todas as mudanças que ocorreram durante a transação.

É recomendado utilizar `commit` em todas as operações que envolvam banco, até nas consultas. Ficaria parecido com isso:

```
public Object buscaPorId(Long id,Class<?> classe){
    try{
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        return manager.find(classe, id);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```